# How to stop images getting stretched inside a Flexbox Container in Foundation 6.4.3 Card?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, zurb-foundation

I was making a layout to create an image grid using **Zurb Foundation 6.4.3** XY Grid's Card Component. All my images are actually 320x180 px in dimension. But when I am running the following Code images are getting stretched.

I am new in CSS3 Flexbox and Foundation XY Grid and not being able to find out what is happening here. I will be grateful if someone help me to find out a solution.

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundation/6.4.3/css/foundation.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="grid-x medium-up-3">

    <div class="cell">
      <div class="card">
        <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/XE9GX.png`enter code here`" />


      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="cell">
      <div class="card">

        <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/XE9GX.png" />


      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="cell">
      <div class="card">

        <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/XE9GX.png" />


      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="cell">
      <div class="card">

        <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/XE9GX.png" />


      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="cell">
      <div class="card">

        <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/XE9GX.png" />


      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="cell">
      <div class="card">
        <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/XE9GX.png" />


      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Tested this in Firefox and Chrome and it renders the same in both. How do you mean it stretches?

Comment: Yes, when I am running this code it is not stretching. But look here https://codepen.io/coolsaint/pen/JrGdXE it is the same code and the images are getting stretched.

Comment: @LGSon Got the Code Snippet fixed now. It was actually not inserting the Zurb Foundation CSS library to the Snippet. Now I have edited it and images are getting stretched.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add `align-self` to your `img` (the *stretching* happens as the `align-items` property is `stretch` by default in the *flex direction*). You can also add `align-items: center` to your `card`.

If so needed, you can throw in a `width: 100%` too for the `img` (for the image to scale evenly) - see demo below:

```css
.card img {
  align-self: center;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundation/6.4.3/css/foundation.css' />

<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="grid-x medium-up-3">

    <div class="cell">
      <div class="card">
        <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/XE9GX.png`enter code here`" />


      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="cell">
      <div class="card">

        <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/XE9GX.png" />


      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="cell">
      <div class="card">

        <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/XE9GX.png" />


      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="cell">
      <div class="card">

        <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/XE9GX.png" />


      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="cell">
      <div class="card">

        <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/XE9GX.png" />


      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="cell">
      <div class="card">
        <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/XE9GX.png" />


      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

A foundation based solution would be to use:

1. Use `grid-x` and `align-center` for the grid wrapper.
2. Use the following markup for *cell*:

   ```
   <div class="shrink cell">
     <div class="card">
       <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/XE9GX.png`enter code here`">
     </div>
   </div>
   ```

See demo below:

```html
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundation/6.4.3/css/foundation.css">

  <div class="grid-container">
    <div class="grid-x align-center">

      <div class="shrink cell">
        <div class="card">
          <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/XE9GX.png`enter code here`">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="shrink cell">
        <div class="card">
          <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/XE9GX.png`enter code here`">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="shrink cell">
        <div class="card">
          <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/XE9GX.png`enter code here`">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="shrink cell">
        <div class="card">
          <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/XE9GX.png`enter code here`">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="shrink cell">
        <div class="card">
          <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/XE9GX.png`enter code here`">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="shrink cell">
        <div class="card">
          <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/XE9GX.png`enter code here`">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="shrink cell">
        <div class="card">
          <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/XE9GX.png`enter code here`">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="shrink cell">
        <div class="card">
          <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/XE9GX.png`enter code here`">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="shrink cell">
        <div class="card">
          <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/XE9GX.png`enter code here`">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Thanks man. It is working. But why there are lot of spaces I mean margin around the images? is it default flexbox behavior or happening because of foundation css?

Comment: Try `width: 100%` on the  `img`?

Comment: Then it is stretching again.

Comment: Will you change your answer to this foundation framework specific solution or I can do it if you want. I will be glad to accept the answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154714/discussion-between-coolsaint-and-kukkuz).